# How to read unformatted contents of the numeric cells using NPOI?

Tags: c#, excel-2007, npoi

I want to read an unformatted contents of the numeric cells (e.g. `0.05` instead of `5%` and `123456` instead of `123,456.000`).

I thought the easiest way to do it would be to change the format of the cell:

```
ICell cell = ...;
string s = cell.SetCellType(<ICell.CELL_TYPE_STRING-doesn't compile>).ToString();
```

but I do not know how to set string/numeric format.

All examples I have googled are either from `POI` or `HSSF` universes, they won't do for me (I am reading `Excel 2007` spreadsheet using `NPOI`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
string formatProofCellReading(ICell cell)
{
    if (cell == null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if (cell.CellType == CellType.NUMERIC)
    {
        double d = cell.NumericCellValue;
        return (d.ToString());
    }
    return cell.ToString();
}
```